# Asegurar ingreso de variable GET

Tags: php

Les comento lo que me ocurre, deseo hacer un archivo expulsar.php que se encargue de hacer un UPDATE para cambiar a 0 algunos valores en la tabla cuenta.

Los valores que necesita este archivo serian uid y rut, pero me puse a pensar que si hago un href y mando esas variables por get al presionar en expulsar miembro, cualquiera que conozca el rut y el uid del usuario simplemente lo pone en la url y expulsa a cualquiera, entonces habia pensado en pasar un token que se genere aleatoriamente pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo. Si alguien tiene para recomendarme una forma segura de hacer esto les agradeceria su colaboracion. Saludos y gracias

Comment: También puedes usar $_POST en el cual no se pasan los parámetros en la url.

Comment: Deberías tener una tabla de permisos y comprobar si el usuario que quiere expulsar a otro está autorizado para ello.

Comment: @Error404 que se haga con GET o POST no importa. Si el usuario conoce el uid y rut de otro usuario podría borrarlo independientemente de que el método usado para enviar los datos sea GET o POST. Hay que añadir algún tipo de privilegio y/o comprobación en el lado del servidor como indica AntoTGa.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Sí, eso está claro. Por supuesto hay que hacer una doble comprobación pero utilizando $_POST al menos las variables no irán dentro de la url.

Comment: @Error404 Si ya tengo claro eso, pero como te dice  Alvaro existen mil maneras de enviarle datos por post a un servidor. Gracias tomare en cuenta lo de hacer que el usuario este logueado para eso y usar los privilegios que tengo, muchas gracias por la idea.

Comment: @SantiagoD'Antuoni Sí, de hecho, por si quieres investigar un poco más sobre eso, una de las maneras de poner un sistema de privilegios es mediante una ACL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es mejor hacerlo por método `POST` como te han mencionado, ya que vas hacer un `UPDATE`. Aun así te voy a dejar un ejemplo como enviar un `ID` protegido de ida y vuelta por método `GET`.

Generamos una `clave` y la guardas en tu servidor, ya en tu archivo conexión `PHP` o en tu Base de datos, es decir, un lugar seguro, para así poder trabajar con el cuándo sea necesario.

```
    $clave = 'KFpt%5WAQR%ZMBJ-'; //Generamos clave.
```

Creamos el `ID` protegido con la función `MD5` y añadimos la clave e ID.

```
$id_protegido = md5($clave.$tu_id);
```

La `url`quedaria así:

```
echo "<a href=url.php?id=$id_protegido>abrir</a>";
```

Veamos el proceso como recibir del `id` con protección y crear nuestra consulta `SQL`.

```
//Obtenemos ID.
$id = $_GET['id'] ?: '';

//Nota, $clave la debes obtener para concatenar la cadena para asi hacer la comprobación del 'id' correctamente.

//Sentencia prepare.
$stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT id,nombre,expulsar FROM tu_tabla WHERE md5(CONCAT(?, id)) = ?");
//Ligamos parametros marcadores.
$stmt->bind_param("si",$clave,$id);
//Ejecutar sentencia.
$stmt->execute();
//Registros almacenados.
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows===1){
   //Salida data.
   $stmt->bind_result($id_BD,$nombre,$expulsar);
   $stmt->fetch();
   //Cerrar sentencia.
   $stmt->close();
} else { $stmt->close(); }
```

Comment: Gracias me diste una buena idea para proximos casos (? pero en este caso creo que me ire por la facil y usare autentificacion del usuario y sus permisos, de todas formas muchas gracias, te deje mi voto. Buen aporte